# What is the problem with Identity, ApplicationDbContext, and UnitOfWork in my MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I try to add Identity to my MVC project. I've added identity scaffolded item, but the project won't start when after I added it.

This is the error code i get:

> System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType
> : KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Un
> able to resolve service for type 'KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repositor
> y.UnitOfWork'.)
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUn
> itOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'KjeksFabrikken.DataA
> ccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to act
> ivate 'KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChai
> n, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type impl
> ementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChai
> n callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChai
> n)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProv
> iderOptions options)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\David\RiderProjects3\KjeksFabrikken\KjeksFabrikken\Program.cs:line 18

This is my ApplicationDbContext.cs file:

```
using KjeksFabrikken.Models.Models;
using KjeksFabrikken.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Cookie = KjeksFabrikken.Models.Models.Cookie;

namespace KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Data;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<Cookie> Cookies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CookieCategory> CookieCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CookieIngredient> CookieIngredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactInput> ContactInputs { get; set; }

}
```

This is my IUnitOfWork.cs file:

```
namespace KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    ICookieRepository Cookie { get; }
    ISaveContactInputRepository SaveContactInput { get; set; }
    ISendContactInputRepository SendContactInput { get; set; }
    void Save();
}
```

This is my UnitOfWork.cs file:

```
using KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Data;
using KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;

namespace KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository;

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        Cookie = new CookieRepository(_db);
        SaveContactInput = new SaveContactInputRepository(_db);
        SendContactInput = new SendContactInputRepository(_db);
    }
    
    public ICookieRepository Cookie { get; set; }
    
    public ISaveContactInputRepository SaveContactInput { get; set; }
    
    public ISendContactInputRepository SendContactInput { get; set; }
    
    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is my Program.cs file:

```
using KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Data;
using KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository;
using KjeksFabrikken.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Here is the NuGet packages I have installed on the project:

[Nuget Packages installed on MVC project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72pRr.png)

I am new to MVC and Asp.Net so i don't know what the problem is. I don't understand the error message, and I know the applicationdbcontext and unitofwork was working perfectly before adding identity. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the root, and solution, to this problem. After adding Identity (scaffolded item), a "Areas" folder was generated in the project. In the "Identity" folder inside the "Areas" folder, there is also generated a "Data" folder. ("Areas" -> "Identity" -> "Data").

Inside the "Data" folder, the identity scaffolded item generated another "ApplicationDbContext.cs" file. So the app generated another applicationdbcontext file, even if I already had one from before.

After deleting the "Data" folder (in the "Identity" folder), with the generated "ApplicationDbContext.cs" file, the app was finally working.